# Alexa.Discovery response: no device detected by Alexa

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am implementing my Alexa Home Skill using AWS Lambda.

Given the following request I receive when I try to detect new devices on Alexa Skil test page:

```
{directive={header={namespace=Alexa.Discovery, name=Discover, payloadVersion=3, messageId=0160c7e7-031f-47ee-a1d9-a23f38f87a9e}, payload={scope={type=BearerToken, token=...}}}}
```

I respond with the following:

```
{
    "event": {
        "payload": {
            "endpoints": [
                {
                    "displayCategories": [
                        "SMARTPLUG"
                    ],
                    "capabilities": [
                        {
                            "type": "AlexaInterface",
                            "interface": "Alexa",
                            "version": "3"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "AlexaInterface",
                            "interface": "Alexa.PowerController",
                            "version": "3",
                            "properties": {
                                "retrievable": true,
                                "supported": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "powerState"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "proactivelyReported": true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "AlexaInterface",
                            "interface": "Alexa.EndpointHealth",
                            "version": "3",
                            "properties": {
                                "retrievable": true,
                                "supported": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "connectivity"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "proactivelyReported": true
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "manufacturerName": "mirko.io",
                    "endpointId": "ca84ef6d-53b1-430a-8a5e-a62f174eac5e",
                    "description": "mirko.io forno (id: ca84ef6d-53b1-430a-8a5e-a62f174eac5e)",
                    "friendlyName": "forno"
                }
            ]
        },
        "header": {
            "payloadVersion": "3",
            "namespace": "Alexa.Discovery",
            "name": "Discover.Response",
            "messageId": "c0555cc8-ad7a-4377-b310-9de9b9ab6282"
        }
    }
}
```

Despite that, for some reasons Alexa answers that it did not find any new device.
I may be mistaken but I am pretty sure it used to work before I decided to add the Alexa.EndpointHealth interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your response object looks right to me, except the extra `"endpoint"` field.

```
"endpoint": {
            "endpointId": "INVALID",
            "scope": {
                "type": "BearerToken",
                "token": "INVALID"
            }
        }
```

There's no such field in the [Alexa.Discovery](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-discovery.html) documentation. Try removing it and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: thanks for your response. That part of the message comes from the Alexa Github example (https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-java-smarthome-switch/blob/e9c0d10225093374df42118bbb41a3d8f60c409d/src/main/java/AlexaResponse.java). Anyway, I ripped it off, with no luck.